# Track merged changesets from deleted branch

Tags: svn, tfs, branching-and-merging, changeset, source-control-explorer

I find the 'Track Changeset' feature in TFS useful to allow me to visualise which changesets have been merged into Main which works as an audit when checking the state of our codebase.

However when a branch has been merged and subsequently deleted I am unable to retrieve the changeset that was merged.  How do I discover that the newly deleted branch was brought into Main before being deleted?

This is trivial in SVN (as we have the 'Copy from path' and 'Revision' columns against each file).  Therefore how would I do this in TFS?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn deleted files on in the UI. In visual studio go to Tools | Options | Source Control and select "Show deleted files".

I am not sure if your will get everything that you want but you should be able to trace the history.

Comment: Many thanks, I've managed to turn this on but it unfortunately I'm unable to choose these in the 'Track Changeset' tool.  It's as though the source of the code in Main came from nowhere

Comment: Your branching model seams more conducive to a Git repository and not TFVC. Have you thought about migrating your code to a Git repo within TFS?

Comment: That's true, however this branching model works fine in other centralised source control systems (SVN).  Although I understand TFS is much more anti-branch I would still expect this to be available for such a mature product.  Git is not an option for us.

Comment: I would not delete branches personally.  Just mark them either read/only or remove permissions for people to see them except for the "merge master" for lack of a better tittle.