# Is there a way to get back the changeset history of the deleted branch?

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc, changeset, revision-history

I'm accustomed with the gitflow approach and git-based repositories.
In my current project we are using TFS with an in-house TFVC based repo and I'm struggling with reviewing the history off changes.

What I've done:

1. Branched from `master` to `feature/SomeFeature`.
2. Done some work on `feature/SomeFeature` (about 30 check-ins).
3. Merged back to `master`.
4. Once I'm sure that every conflicts and code were successfully merged I've deleted `feature/SomeFeature`

And then I've looked into the History of `master` and saw only the merge check-in.

That means the whole check-ins history in-between is lost?

Is there any way to merge branches with moving the check-ins like in the git-based repositories?

Comment: Consider tagging this question as Git. I suspect it's really a Git question, not TFS.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's git related because we are using tfs as a version control so I guess "Team Foundation Version Control" would be better.

Comment: Right. Do you know whether you are using TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) or Git with TFS? I presumed Git because of the reference to "master". However, that is not exactly a reliable indicator - but it suggests Git.

Comment: This may be helpful: "Azure (TFS) Repos supports two types of version control: Git and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC)."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops

Comment: @ScottWelker We're using TFVC, I've used `master` because that's how devs actually named the production branch. We have our repo shipped on a centralized in-house server. I've edited the question to state it clearly, thank you for pointing out the possible source of confusion.

Comment: I don't know much about TFVC but if it is like SVN you probably should not be deleting branches, even merged ones. Otherwise you should be exploring deleted files for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896336/track-merged-changesets-from-deleted-branch)

Comment: In Visual Studio you should see something like (Tools | Options, Source Control) "show deleted items..." 

I haven't used TFSVS in sometime so I'm posting as a comment. I can't be certain of the exact steps and it depends on your Visual Studio version (assuming you are not using TFS' Web Interface).